# When reading aloud, how to read a parenthetical phrase?

Tags: speech

I need to read a script for a kind of audition, and part of the script contains a phrase in parentheses.

Ie:
"To approve an Amended and Restated Investment Advisory and Administration Agreement (“Proposed Advisory Agreement”) between..."

I'm not sure if I should say *or "proposed advisory agreement"*, or say AKA, or what.

Comment: [Air quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_quotes) come to mind (think Dr. Evil), but I'm fairly sure that that is not how a lawyer or judge would read the defined term aloud. Maybe they'd say (indeed) "or" or "henceforth" or something.

Comment: Who wrote this script?  I've never seen someone write dialogue this way in screenwriting.  Usually they would write "beat" or "pause" before and after the parenthetical statement, to indicate how it should be spoken.  Regardless, if it's for an audition, I wouldn't add words that aren't written in the script.  I would just pause briefly before and after the parenthetical phrase.

Comment: It's not like a script for a screen play or something. It's for a call center job and apparently they want me to read this to their answering machine, i guess as kind of an audition? Thank you for the advice. I definitely won't add anything that's not written.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a trick to this.  First of all, you put

> (“Proposed Advisory Agreement”)

in a lower pitch than the surrounding text.  Second, your intonation needs to go up in the second to last parenthetical syllable (*gree*), and then dip down and back up in the last (*ment*).